# ECS with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

Is there a good / definitive reference or course for managing a ECS service using Terraform. I have referred [this](http://blog.shippable.com/setup-a-container-cluster-on-aws-with-terraform-part-2-provision-a-cluster) which creates the ECS Service, but I can't get to a state where my task runs on that cluster.

Here is what I have for now:

```
# create the VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block           = var.cidr_vpc
  instance_tenancy     = var.instanceTenancy
  enable_dns_support   = var.dnsSupport
  enable_dns_hostnames = var.dnsHostNames
  tags = {
    Name = "tdemo"
  }
}

# Create the Internet Gateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  tags = {
    Name = "tdemo"
  }
}

# Create the Public subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_public1" {
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  cidr_block              = var.cidr_pubsubnet1
  map_public_ip_on_launch = "true"
  availability_zone       = var.availability_zone1
  tags = {
    Name = "tdemo"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_public2" {
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  cidr_block              = var.cidr_pubsubnet2
  map_public_ip_on_launch = "true"
  availability_zone      = var.availability_zone2
  tags = {
    Name = "tdemo"
  }
}

# Route table to connect to Internet Gateway
resource "aws_route_table" "rta_public" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.igw.id}"
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "tdemo"
  }
}

# Create Route Table Association to make the subet public over internet
resource "aws_route_table_association" "rta_subnet_public" {
  subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.subnet_public1.id}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.rta_public.id}"
}

# Configure Security Group inbound and outbound rules
resource "aws_security_group" "sg_22" {
  name   = "sg_22"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "tdemo"
  }
}

###############################################################################
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs-service-role" {
  name               = "tdemo-ecs-service-role"
  path               = "/"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs-service-policy.json}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs-service-role-attachment" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.ecs-service-role.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs-service-policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs-instance-role" {
  name               = "tdemo-ecs-instance-role"
  path               = "/"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs-instance-policy.json}"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs-instance-policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs-instance-role-attachment" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.ecs-instance-role.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ecs-instance-profile" {
  name  = "tdemo-ecs-instance-profile"
  path  = "/"
  roles = ["${aws_iam_role.ecs-instance-role.id}"]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11 > nul"
  }
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "ecs-launch-configuration" {
  name                 = "tdemo-ecs-launch-configuration"
  image_id             = var.amiid
  instance_type        = "t2.xlarge"
  iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs-instance-profile.id}"

  root_block_device {
    volume_type           = "standard"
    volume_size           = 100
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  security_groups             = ["${aws_security_group.sg_22.id}"]
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  key_name                    = "${var.ecs_public_keyname}"
  user_data                   = <<-EOF
    #! /bin/bash
    echo ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
    sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=524288
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y apache2
    sudo systemctl start apache2
    sudo systemctl enable apache2
    echo "<h1>Deployed via Terraform</h1>" | sudo tee /var/www/html/index.html
    EOF
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "ecs-cluster" {
    name = var.ecs_cluster
}

###############################################################################
data "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs_task_definition" {
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs_task_definition.family}"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs_task_definition" {
  family                = "hello_world"
  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
  [
    {
      "name": "hello-world",
      "image": "nginx:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "memory": 500,
      "cpu": 10
    }
  ]
  DEFINITION
}

resource "aws_alb" "ecs-load-balancer" {
    name                = "ecs-load-balancer"
    security_groups     = ["${aws_security_group.sg_22.id}"]
    subnets             = ["${aws_subnet.subnet_public1.id}", "${aws_subnet.subnet_public2.id}"]

    tags = {
      Name = "ecs-load-balancer"
    }
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "ecs-target-group" {
    name                = "ecs-target-group"
    port                = "80"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    vpc_id              = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

    health_check {
        healthy_threshold   = "5"
        unhealthy_threshold = "2"
        interval            = "30"
        matcher             = "200"
        path                = "/"
        port                = "traffic-port"
        protocol            = "HTTP"
        timeout             = "5"
    }

    tags = {
      Name = "ecs-target-group"
    }
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "alb-listener" {
    load_balancer_arn = "${aws_alb.ecs-load-balancer.arn}"
    port              = "80"
    protocol          = "HTTP"

    default_action {
        target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.ecs-target-group.arn}"
        type             = "forward"
    }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ecs-autoscaling-group" {
    name                        = "ecs-autoscaling-group"
    max_size                    = "${var.max_instance_size}"
    min_size                    = "${var.min_instance_size}"
    desired_capacity            = "${var.desired_capacity}"
    vpc_zone_identifier         = ["${aws_subnet.subnet_public1.id}", "${aws_subnet.subnet_public2.id}"]
    launch_configuration        = "${aws_launch_configuration.ecs-launch-configuration.name}"
    health_check_type           = "ELB"
  }

resource "aws_ecs_service" "ecs-service" {
    name            = "tdemo-ecs-service"
    iam_role        = "${aws_iam_role.ecs-service-role.name}"
    cluster         = "${aws_ecs_cluster.ecs-cluster.id}"
    task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs_task_definition.family}:${max("${aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs_task_definition.revision}", "${data.aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs_task_definition.revision}")}"
    desired_count   = 1

    load_balancer {
        target_group_arn  = "${aws_alb_target_group.ecs-target-group.arn}"
        container_port    = 80
        container_name    = "hello-world"
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is apparent and that may be the source of the issue (at least one of them) is:

```
echo ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

However, your cluster name is `var.ecs_cluster`. Thus the above line should be:

```
echo ECS_CLUSTER=${var.ecs_cluster} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

Please note, that there could be many other issues, which are not that clear to spot without actually deploying your terraform script.

Comment: You don't need to specify a capacity provider for that to work. As long as there are EC2 instances running the ECS agent that register themselves with the cluster (by specifying it in the ecs.config file as mentioned above) then they will be able to run tasks.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Thanks, I removed that.